# matrix post processing issue

Tags: python, csv, matrix

If this is my array :

```py
csv_arr_output = [
    ["",        "",       "Average", "",    "Red"     ],
    ["",        "",       "",        "",    "Red eyes"],
    ["",        "height", "weight",  "",    ""        ],
    ["Males",   "1.9",    "0.003",   "40%", ""        ],
    ["Females", "1.7",    "0.002",   "43%", ""        ],
]
```

to be later converted to csv file but i post process it using this function :

```
    def post_processing(csv_array, common_percent_threshold=0.5):
        # Replace longer next cell if they have a certain percent of common string
        for row in range(len(csv_array) - 1):
            for col in range(len(csv_array[row])):
                current_cell = csv_array[row][col]
                next_cell = csv_array[row + 1][col]
    
                if calculate_common_percent(current_cell, next_cell) >= common_percent_threshold:
                    if len(current_cell) < len(next_cell):
                        csv_array[row][col] = next_cell
                        csv_array[row + 1][col] = ""
    
        # Merge empty cells in the same column
        for col in range(len(csv_array[0])):
            column_cells = [row[col] for row in csv_array]
            non_empty_cells = [cell for cell in column_cells if cell != ""]
            empty_cells = [""] * (len(column_cells) - len(non_empty_cells))
    
            for row in range(len(csv_array)):
                if csv_array[row][col] == "":
                    csv_array[row][col] = empty_cells.pop(0)
    
        # Remove empty rows
        csv_array = [row for row in csv_array if any(cell != "" for cell in row)]
    
        return csv_array
    
    def calculate_common_percent(cell1, cell2):
        set1 = set(cell1.split())
        set2 = set(cell2.split())
        
        # Check if both sets are empty
        if not set1 and not set2:
            return 0.0
        
        common_words = set1.intersection(set2)
        total_words = set1.union(set2)
        
        # Avoid division by zero
        if not total_words:
            return 0.0
        
        return len(common_words) / len(total_words)
```

and this is the output i got :

```py
[
    ["",        "",       "Average", "",    "Red eyes"],
    ["",        "height", "weight",  "",    ""        ],
    ["Males",   "1.9",    "0.003",   "40%", ""        ],
    ["Females", "1.7",    "0.002",   "43%", ""        ],
]
```

As you can see below the column Red eyes all the cells are empty i want to shif red eyes to the left and then remove the empty column colud you please help me to integrate this logic in this function

I am expecting for the post processing function to do all its functionallty in addition to shifting the column header that has below it empty cells and then removign all the empty column from the matrix

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question. What is your specific problem with implementing this functionality?

Comment: I tried to implement it but it didn't turn out as I expected

Comment: Show your code anyway together with an explanation of "didn't turn out as I expected".

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a 2-dimesional list that looks like:

```py
l = [
    ["",        "",       "Average", "",    "Red"     ],
    ["",        "",       "",        "",    "Red eyes"],
    ["",        "height", "weight",  "",    ""        ],
    ["Males",   "1.9",    "0.003",   "40%", ""        ],
    ["Females", "1.7",    "0.002",   "43%", ""        ],
]
```

You can:

- move "Red eyes" up and over
- delete the empty row
- delete the last (5th) column

like:

```py
# move 'Red eyes' up and over
l[0][3] = l[1][4]

# delete unnecessary row
del l[1]

# trim 5th cell from each row (effectively deleting 5th column)
l = [x[0:4] for x in l]

print(l)
```

That gives me:

```py
[
    ["",        "",       "Average", "Red eyes"],
    ["",        "height", "weight",  ""        ],
    ["Males",   "1.9",    "0.003",   "40%"     ],
    ["Females", "1.7",    "0.002",   "43%"     ],
]
```